# two scrollable columns with bootstrap

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, layout

I try to make a layout with two scrollable columns (with bootstrap 2.2). Now it seems to be working if i remove the "!doctype html" tag so i assume something with my layout is not according to the specification. Can somebody tell me what i did wrong or how i could easier find my error?

```
<!doctype html> <!-- scrolling only works without the doctype -->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">

<head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="bootstrap.min.css">

    <script src="jquery-1.7.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        body, html {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .navbar-inner {
            height: 40px;
        }

        .scrollable {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: auto;
        }

        .max-height {
            height: 100%;
        }

        .no-overflow {
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        .pad40-top {
            padding-top: 40px;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li><a href="#serials" data-toggle="tab">Serials</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#parameters" data-toggle="tab">Parameter</a></li>
                    <li class="active"><a href="#log" data-toggle="tab">Log</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container max-height no-overflow">
    <div class="row max-height">

        <div class="tabbable tabs-left">

                 <div class="tab-pane active" id="log">

                    <div class="span2 scrollable">
                        <div class="pad40-top">
                            First menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br    >menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu    </br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>    menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu<    /br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>    menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu<    /br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>menu</br>main
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="span10 scrollable">
                        <div class="pad40-top">
                            First Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>    Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br    >Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</    br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content<    /br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content</br>Content    </br>Content</br>Content</br>

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: What is the issue, I can see scrolling works on the left with and without doctype in Chrome 22!

Comment: Thanks for your test. On my chrome 22 (and firefox 16 and safari 6) it only works without the doctype. With the doctype i can't scroll at all. You can scroll the menu column independent from the Content column?

Comment: I **can't** scroll the menu. It stays still. BTW, my screen resolution is `1280 x 1024`, and what's yours? Can you post a screenshot or something?

Comment: With the doctype i can't scroll whatever the screen resolution is. Without the doctype i can scroll as soon as the window is smaller than the content.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- correct the many, many `</br>` `</br   >` etc tags
- `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/html">` should be `<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`
- add a `<title>`
- remove the stray `</div>` at the bottom

Now you have a html5 doc that validates. To get the scrollables to work, you must give either `body` or `.scrollable` a height. You cannot have a scrollable defined as 100% of 100%.

if you set

```
 .scrollable {
            height: 500px;
            overflow: auto;
        }
```

it works, OR - set the height dynamically in javascript :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var h=$(window).height();
    $('.scrollable').height(h+'px');
});
</script>
```

note : the code just simulates the 100%->100%, top of the scrollables is still behind the navbar, and you must implement some code to take care of window resizing.

cleaned markup :

```
 <!doctype html> 
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <style type="text/css">
            body, html {
                height: 100%;
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .navbar-inner {
                height: 40px;
            }

            .scrollable {
                height: 500px;
                overflow: auto;
            }

            .max-height {
                height: 100%;
            }

            .no-overflow {
                overflow: hidden;
            }

            .pad40-top {
                padding-top: 40px;
            }
        </style>

    <!--  or :
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var h=$(window).height();
        $('.scrollable').height(h+'px');
    });
    </script>
   -->

    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="navbar-inner">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
                    <a class="brand" href="#">Title</a>
                    <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                        <li><a href="#serials" data-toggle="tab">Serials</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#parameters" data-toggle="tab">Parameter</a></li>
                        <li class="active"><a href="#log" data-toggle="tab">Log</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container max-height no-overflow">
        <div class="row max-height">

            <div class="tabbable tabs-left">

                     <div class="tab-pane active" id="log">

                        <div class="span2 scrollable">
                            <div class="pad40-top">
                                First menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu    <br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>    menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>    menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>menu<br>main
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="span10 scrollable">
                            <div class="pad40-top">
                                First Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>    Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content<br>Content    <br>Content<br>Content<br>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

Comment: Thanks. I found now some validation tool which checks my html... So scrolling is only possible on a div with a fixed height? (I use the js solution with some code for resize)

Comment: gr8! Yes, there must be something the reader can use to evaluate if it should show scrollbars or not. Think about it, how would you code for an event, where an element should be 100% of 100%? There is alternatives, you can use max-height, not supported correctly in all browsers, and instead of auto, look at overflow-y